# Magento 2 custom admin theme error

Tags: magento2

I have a custom basic admin theme but when active and I go to the admin area edit a product I get this error still.

```
[2020-11-13 09:46:46] main.ERROR: Unable to load theme by specified key: '' [] []
```

This is my di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- Admin theme. Start -->
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">default/default</item> <!-- Example: "Magento/backend" -->
                <!-- fix "Incorrect theme identification key" -->
                <item name="crontab" xsi:type="string">Magento/backend</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <!-- Admin theme. End -->
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your theme exists & check theme id in the database:

```
select theme_id,theme_title from theme;
```

then check if theme id is the same as the active theme in the database:

```
select * from core_config_data  where path like '%theme%';
```

Update to correct theme id if different.

Comment: I have a frontend theme id set for ```design/theme/theme_id``` but the admin theme is a different ID. How do I tell the admin area to use my admin theme